# Map value empty outside a for each in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have just started programming in scala. I'm also using Apache spark for reading a file - **moviesFile**. In the following code, I'm updating a mutable map inside a foreach function. The map is updated within the foreach function. But the values are not present once the foreach exits.

How to make the values remain permanent in the map variable **movieMap**.

```
 val movieMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String]()
 val movie = moviesFile.map(_.split("::")).foreach { 
    x => x.mkString(" ")
    val movieid = x(0)
    val title = x(1)
    val genre = x(2)
    val value = title+","+genre
    movieMap(movieid.toString()) = value.toString()
    println(movieMap.keySet)
}
println(movieMap.keySet)
println(movieMap.get("29"))
```

Comment: Well... first of all... I don't see you using Spark at all. Is `movieFile` and `RDD` ?

Comment: Also... why do you want a `Map` which is a non-distributed data structure ( potentially nullifying most of Spark benefits on future uses of this Map) when you can use  `PairRDDFunctions` available to `pair-like RDD's`

Comment: Replace this - `movieMap(movieid.toString()) = value.toString()` by `movieMap.update( movieid.toString(),  value.toString() )` and your problem should be solved.

Comment: I did an invalid assignment in the above code. I declared movieMap which is actually declared in the Master of the spark and the servant/slave will do the "moviesFile.map(_.split("::")).foreach...." code. So the updated movieMap will not be reflected in the slave. To avoid this I assigned the value of "moviesFile.map(_.split("::")).foreach..." to the variable movieMap instead of the movie variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are using Spark in a very wrong way. If you want to utilize Spark, you will have to use Spark's distributed data structures.

I will suggest to stay with Spark's distributed and parallelized data structure ( `RDD's` ). RDD's which contain `( key, value ) pairs` are implicitly provided with some Map-like functionality.

```
Import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

// Assume sc is the SparkContext instance

val moviesFileRdd = sc.textFile("movies.txt")

// moviesRdd is RDD[ ( String, String ) ] which acts as a Map-like thing of ( key, value ) pairs
val moviesRdd = moviesFileRdd.map( line =>
  val splitLine = line.split( "::" )
  val movieId = splitLine(0)
  val title = splitLine(1)
  val genre = splitLine(2)
  val value = title + ", " + genre
  ( movieId.toString, value.toString )
)

// You see... RDD[ ( String, String ) ] offers some map-like things.
// get a list of all values with key 29
val listOfValuesWithKey29 = moviesRdd.lookup( "29" )

// I don't know why ? but if you really need a map here then
val moviesMap = moviesRdd.collectAsMap

// moviesMap will be a immutable Map, in case you need a mutable Map,
val moviesMutableMap = mutable.Map( moviesMap.toList: _* )
```

Comment: `I believe that you are using Spark in a very wrong way` Can you explain why?

Comment: Because OP is actually not using anything from at all.